# Speed up the computation for numpy.asarray

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am given the following code which generates random integers and convert them into their binary repsentation:

```
import sys
import random
import numpy

num = 500000
M = list(set([random.randint(0, 2 ** 64) for i in range(num)]))
M = [('{0:016b}').format(i) for i in M]
M = numpy.asarray([list(map(int, list(i))) for i in M])
```

`num` could be any value from 1 million up to 20 million. As you may notice, the last line `M = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(i))) for i in M])` is where the most computation time takes. How can I speed it up? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `num=5`, your code produces

```
In [62]: M
Out[62]: 
array([ list([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]),
       list([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]),
       list([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]),
       list([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]),
       list([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])], dtype=object)
In [63]: M.shape
Out[63]: (5,)
In [64]: len(M[0])
Out[64]: 64
In [65]: [len(m) for m in M]
Out[65]: [64, 64, 64, 62, 64]
```

`M` is a 1d object array, essentially a glorified/debased list.  Components are lists.  They vary in length, so the array cannot be 2d (of ints).

Most of the time in the last line is in the list comprehension, not the `asarray` call.